# Fetch most recent value - sql execution time too long

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a Firebird database with a table with two columns: Date and value.

I want to get the most recent value. Problem is, that this table can have easily over 200k rows. My select query takes more than 400ms, which is just to long for my application. Is there any way, I can speed this up?

I can't change the database in any way. I cannot use any window function introduced in Firebird 3.0.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  REG_DATE_TIME,REG_VAL FROM TAB_REG_VAL  
WHERE REG_DATE_TIME = (SELECT MAX(REG_DATE_TIME)  FROM TAB_REG_VAL);
```

I also tried `select first .. order by`, but the execution time was similar.
I am using C# ado.net connected layer, if that's important.

Comment: What are the index definitions for this table?

Comment: Also what are the datatypes involved, and for `reg_val`: how wide is the column (ie: what is the average actual length)?

Comment: how often do you write into that table and how often do you read? Another solution could be creating a special caching table, where your database triggers would copy most recent rows.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there are no indexes yet. Reg val is float, the actual  length really depends on the table (user specified).

Comment: @Arioch'The Writing to database: it depends on the configuration (the values in the database are measurements - temperature/flow rate etc).
In the worst case scenario, I am writing to db few times every seconds, and I am reading twice as much

Comment: Floats have a fixed width of 4 bytes, so there is no variance in length. I was more asking to check you weren't having rows with 100s if not 1000s of characters in a char or varchar column

Comment: Oh, ok. I know about fixed length, just misunderstood your question and got confused :)

Comment: @KarolŻurowski frequency does not matter here, ratio does. With 2:1 r:w of course caching makes little sense. But would it be like 10:1 or perhaps typical for WWW 100:1 and more - then a cache might be better than index

Comment: That being said, writing sensors directly into DB usually is not considered good idea, without pre-buffering into flat files.

Comment: @Arioch'The thanks, for your insight. I will definitely consider this caching table. In my case write ratio is always greater than read ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a descending [index](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-idx) for the column `REG_DATE_TIME`:

```
create descending index idx_tab_reg_val_reg_date_time on TAB_REG_VAL(REG_DATE_TIME);
```

You can then use

```
SELECT FIRST 1 REG_DATE_TIME,REG_VAL 
FROM TAB_REG_VAL
ORDER BY REG_DATE_TIME DESC
```

Without the index, Firebird will need to materialize and sort the entire result set before it can return you that first row. This is inefficient (and can get even worse if the result set is larger than the sort memory, in which case Firebird will sort in a temporary file on disk).

With the index, Firebird just needs to access a few pages in the index and one or more records in the table to locate the first record that is visible to your transaction.

Note: Firebird indexes can - currently - only be used for sorting in a single direction, which means that depending on your access needs, you may need to create an index in ascending direction as well.

Comment: Thank you.  My query time decreased from 400ms, to around 20ms!!! I have to run some test, but everything looks fine. Also, does adding this index change anything? Because my other programs rely on this database.

Comment: @KarolŻurowski Functionally nothing will change, but there will be a (very small) performance hit on insert/update/delete as the index will also be updated (this is usually only noticeable if you have a lot of indexes on a table). And if the other applications perform similar selects they may also get increased performance from that index.

Comment: "FIRST 1" will have different results if there actually can be several rows with the same timestamp (normal when reading many sensors or multichannel sensor)

Comment: @Arioch'The If records have duplicate timestamps, the results are unstable even without an index, and with an index the order will be more or less guaranteed unless the records get updated.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i meant comparing with his initial query `select ... where timestamp = (select max)` which would issue all such rows, not merely one of them

Comment: @Arioch'The Ah, right, although even that query will benefit from the addition of this index.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
SELECT FIRST (1) REG_DATE_TIME, REG_VAL
FROM TAB_REG_VAL  
ORDER BY REG_DATE_TIME DESC;
```

With an index on `TAB_REG_VAL(REG_DATE_TIME, REG_VAL)`.

Comment: In Firebird you can't order individual columns in an index, only the index as a whole, and including the `reg_val` column for this purpose would not have an added benefit as Firebird will need to read the actual row anyway to check transaction visibility.