# select up-to-date values from Firebird DB

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in Firebird DB - see the [image: picture]

I need to know the up-to-date location information (LOCATION) of each device. Every device has unique serial number (SERIAL_NUMBER). The latest location is the row with highest all counter values (COUNTER1...COUNTER6).
I tried the following query, but it has to be complemented to get what I need. Unfortunately I don't have idea how to modify it.

```
SELECT LOCATION 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER IN (SELECT DISTINCT SERIAL_NUMBER 
                        FROM TABLE) 
ORDER BY COUNTER1, COUNTER2, COUNTER3, COUNTER4, COUNTER5, COUNTER6
```

From the pseudo-answer, now deleted:

> I need to find a row for every SERIAL_NUMBER with the greatest vaule
>   of COUNTER1 and if equal for COUNTER2 and if equal for
>   COUNTER3...COUNTER6. So finally it will be a set of rows for each
>   SERIAL_NUMBER with the latest location information. The Firebird ver.
>   is 2.5 The design is as it is and cannot be changed. There is no
>   timestamp column in the table to find a latest location information in
>   a straight way, so the greatest counters value represents the most
>   current location.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "highest all counter values"? What would be the correct location for `LSE3400308` if the row 204750 was missing, and why?

Comment: Please make desirable query output, so we would understand the logic.

Comment: Please explain what a "device" is.  I don't see it in the table.

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: Please specify the relevant Firebird version and provide sample data and expected output as **text**. Also, what do you mean with _"it has to be complemented to get what I need"_?

Comment: `The latest location is the row with highest all counter values (COUNTER1...COUNTER6)` - that is not possible in such wording, you can get the row (or several rows) with any single COUNTERn maxed. But not with all counters. Because it is easy to make a table where one counter is maxed in one row, and another counter is maxed in another row. Even if your program should not add rows like that, on database level it is possible to happen, thus it is impossible to make a query like that,

Comment: Most probably you have a problem with database design. Why not make one table "current locations of all devices" and another table "history of all locations" ? What is "ID" column? Why Address2 has greater ID than Address3? Shouldn't ID only grow upwards when you insert new locations and never be decreased? Is ID a primary key, backed up by GENERATOR aka SEQUENCE ?

Comment: Read about similar problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659891/fetch-most-recent-value-sql-execution-time-too-long and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391091/select-only-rows-with-last-modified-timestamp-without-duplicate-rows-with-same

Comment: Address 9 and Andres 10 have the same counters exactly. How would you pick between them then? any address randomly?

Comment: You have no timestamp, and it is okay: time resolution, timezones - it may get complicated. But was about your `ID` column? is it ever-increasing? Can we say that later row would always have greater `ID` value than earlier row? or can it go up and down?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff969/1

You would need to make obvious transitions to Firebird SQL flavor:

- Firebird can not insert many rows with one statement.
- Firebird uses `select FIRST(1) .....` syntax instead of `select .... LIMIT 1`

Notice how I use one SELECT query after another, from simple queries building complex ones, testing every simple one (that it really returns what I need) before making mor complex constructions on top of them.

Read here more details about *the process HOW* to grow queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398120/976391

---

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tab(
  id /* INTeger NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT */ serial primary key,
  ser varchar(20) not null,
  Loc varchar(20) not null,
  c1 integer not null,
  c2 integer not null,
  c3 integer not null,
  c4 integer not null,
  c5 integer not null,
  c6 integer not null
 );

 insert into tab(ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
 ('LSE4300308', 'Address 1', 0,0,0, 0,0,0),
 ('LHD4x22414', 'Address 2', 601,504,8, 130,0,0),
 ('LHD4x22414', 'Address 3', 2385,1163,54, 150,0,0),
 ('LSE4300308', 'Address 4', 2209,0,323, 0,0,0),
 ('LSE4300308', 'Address 5', 2257,0,330, 1661,926,0),
 ('LSE4300308', 'Address 6', 2278,0,330, 0,0,0),
 ('LSE4300308', 'Address 7', 2257,0,330, 1661,926,0),
 ('LSE4300308', 'Address 8', 2262,0,330, 1661,926,0),
 ('L873702373', 'Address 9', 12165,25467,1578, 2619,0,0),
 ('L873702373', 'Address A', 12165,25467,1578, 2619,0,0);

 create index t_ser on tab(ser);
 create /* descending */ index t_counters on tab(c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc);
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select * from tab
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff969/1/0)**:

```
| id |        ser |       loc |    c1 |    c2 |   c3 |   c4 |  c5 | c6 |
|----|------------|-----------|-------|-------|------|------|-----|----|
|  1 | LSE4300308 | Address 1 |     0 |     0 |    0 |    0 |   0 |  0 |
|  2 | LHD4x22414 | Address 2 |   601 |   504 |    8 |  130 |   0 |  0 |
|  3 | LHD4x22414 | Address 3 |  2385 |  1163 |   54 |  150 |   0 |  0 |
|  4 | LSE4300308 | Address 4 |  2209 |     0 |  323 |    0 |   0 |  0 |
|  5 | LSE4300308 | Address 5 |  2257 |     0 |  330 | 1661 | 926 |  0 |
|  6 | LSE4300308 | Address 6 |  2278 |     0 |  330 |    0 |   0 |  0 |
|  7 | LSE4300308 | Address 7 |  2257 |     0 |  330 | 1661 | 926 |  0 |
|  8 | LSE4300308 | Address 8 |  2262 |     0 |  330 | 1661 | 926 |  0 |
|  9 | L873702373 | Address 9 | 12165 | 25467 | 1578 | 2619 |   0 |  0 |
| 10 | L873702373 | Address A | 12165 | 25467 | 1578 | 2619 |   0 |  0 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
Select distinct ser from tab
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff969/1/1)**:

```
|        ser |
|------------|
| LSE4300308 |
| L873702373 |
| LHD4x22414 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
Select /* First(10) */ * from tab
  where ser = 'LSE4300308'
  order by c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc
  limit 10
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff969/1/2)**:

```
| id |        ser |       loc |   c1 | c2 |  c3 |   c4 |  c5 | c6 |
|----|------------|-----------|------|----|-----|------|-----|----|
|  6 | LSE4300308 | Address 6 | 2278 |  0 | 330 |    0 |   0 |  0 |
|  8 | LSE4300308 | Address 8 | 2262 |  0 | 330 | 1661 | 926 |  0 |
|  5 | LSE4300308 | Address 5 | 2257 |  0 | 330 | 1661 | 926 |  0 |
|  7 | LSE4300308 | Address 7 | 2257 |  0 | 330 | 1661 | 926 |  0 |
|  4 | LSE4300308 | Address 4 | 2209 |  0 | 323 |    0 |   0 |  0 |
|  1 | LSE4300308 | Address 1 |    0 |  0 |   0 |    0 |   0 |  0 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
Select /* First(1) */ * from tab
  where ser = 'LSE4300308'
  order by c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc
  limit 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff969/1/3)**:

```
| id |        ser |       loc |   c1 | c2 |  c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 |
|----|------------|-----------|------|----|-----|----|----|----|
|  6 | LSE4300308 | Address 6 | 2278 |  0 | 330 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

**Query 5**:

```
Select t1.ser, 
  ( Select /* First(1) */ loc from tab 
    Where ser = t1.ser
    order by c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc
    Limit 1)
From (Select distinct ser from tab) as t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff969/1/4)**:

```
|        ser |       loc |
|------------|-----------|
| LSE4300308 | Address 6 |
| L873702373 | Address 9 |
| LHD4x22414 | Address 3 |
```

---

Firebird 2.1 conversion.
Note - unless this query is run very seldom, you STILL may be better amending the database structure. No matter what is already there, you still can ADD new helper tables and you still can add new `triggers` to keep those new tables up to date automatically. For example one single add-on table "most recent ID for every serial" would make your life simpler, executing `update or insert` command every time new row is inserted into locations.

```
create table so53371903(
  id integer primary key,
  ser varchar(20) not null,
  Loc varchar(20) not null,
  c1 integer not null,
  c2 integer not null,
  c3 integer not null,
  c4 integer not null,
  c5 integer not null,
  c6 integer not null
 );

 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (0,'LSE4300308', 'Address 1', 0,0,0, 0,0,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (1,'LHD4x22414', 'Address 2', 601,504,8, 130,0,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (2,'LHD4x22414', 'Address 3', 2385,1163,54, 150,0,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (3,'LSE4300308', 'Address 4', 2209,0,323, 0,0,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (4,'LSE4300308', 'Address 5', 2257,0,330, 1661,926,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (5,'LSE4300308', 'Address 6', 2278,0,330, 0,0,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (6,'LSE4300308', 'Address 7', 2257,0,330, 1661,926,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (7,'LSE4300308', 'Address 8', 2262,0,330, 1661,926,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (8,'L873702373', 'Address 9', 12165,25467,1578, 2619,0,0)
 ;
 insert into so53371903(id,ser,loc,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) values
   (9,'L873702373', 'Address A', 12165,25467,1578, 2619,0,0)
 ;

 create index t_ser on so53371903(ser);
 create descending index t_counters on so53371903(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6);

Select * from so53371903;

Select distinct ser from so53371903;

Select first(10) * from so53371903
  where ser = 'LSE4300308'
  order by c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc;

Select first(1) * from so53371903
  where ser = 'LSE4300308'
  order by c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc;

Select t1.ser, 
  ( Select First(1) loc from so53371903
    Where ser = t1.ser
    order by c1 desc,c2 desc,c3 desc,c4 desc,c5 desc,c6 desc
   )
From (Select distinct ser from so53371903) as t1;
```

---

Note: `Address 9` and `Address 10` have the same values in counters, so do `Address 5` and `Address 7`. Because there is no "maximum counters" between then - the "winning" row would be chosen at random. It may be that today there will be one winner, and running the same query month or year later would give different result in those rows.